# "Additional Data" in Magento 2 Checkout Order Summary

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have overidden the template:

```
/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/item/details.html
```

For each row, if set, I need to display the "additional_data" field. I can get the value for an arbitrary row by using (e.g. for the first row):

```
window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData[0].additional_data
```

But I can't work out how to display it for the current row in the Knockout template. The $parent object which is used to output the product's price, custom options, etc, does not expose this information.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional options to order items using observer and it will show everywhere.
First need to create events.xml for the observer:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="catalog_product_load_after">
    <observer name="add_additional_option" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\AddAdditionalOption"/>
</event>
```

After that write below code in observer file:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class AddAdditionalOption implements ObserverInterface
{

protected $_request;

public function __construct(
    RequestInterface $request
) {
    $this->_request = $request;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') {             
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $additionalOptions = [];
        $additionalOptions[] = array(
            'label' => "Custom Label",
            'value' => "Custom Info",
        );
        $observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! It now shows up in the cart, summary, order email and admin without the need for any custom templates. Perfect.

I now need to see if I can get the additional options to be displayed *before* the other custom options, as I store the size that the customer ordered in there (hence it's the most important of all of the options)

Comment: Oh, okay - looks like I still need to programmatically add it to the order email and admin order viewer. But that's not too bad!

Comment: great.. Happy coding.. :-)

Comment: Okay, just one more question. Do you know how to carry the additional_options from the quote through to the final order? I've found an observer that uses  *"sales_model_service_quote_submit_before"*, but it doesn't seem to trigger at any point in the checkout flow.

Comment: Okay, no worries - I got it. It's not a frontend event so the definition needed to be in */etc/events.xml* and not */etc/frontend/events.xml*