# Magento 2 How to add custom label and their Value in Order Summary?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, order-summary

I am making Layaways(Buying Products in installments) feature for a website. I have to add custom Lables and the values against them.
I need these Lables and values:

**In Order Summary at the page checkout/#payment:**
[image]

**And on order details page as MY Account->My Orders->View Order**
[image]

Has anyone done anything similar they wish to share to get me started?

Comment: may this will help you, please check  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93349/49315

Comment: Try this out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176699/additional-data-in-magento-2-checkout-order-summary